# Change All in Find/Change changes next paragraph style

Tags: adobe-indesign

What should be a simple Find/Change has turned into so much more.

I'm trying to find all instances of `NAME.` and replace it with `Name` in a specific paragraph style followed by a paragraph break. The following paragraph should remain unchanged.

When I search for this and use the Change or Change/Find command, it works as expected. However, when I use Change All it styles the second paragraph the same as the first.

I've tried with the Text and GREP find options and they yield the same results.

Here's a screenshot of my settings in Text trying to change `Astrid.` to `Astrid^p` : 
[image]

And a screenshot of my settings in GREP with `ASTRID.` to `Astrid/r`: 
[image]

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2rzmafxk9apjkyu/ChangeAllissue.mp4?dl=0)'s a video of exactly what's happening when I hit Change vs Change All.

Hopefully I'm just using it incorrectly and can learn something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you have to do it in two steps because you are not just changing the dot for a paragraph break, the change is a dot for a paragraph break with a paragraph style.

1. `ASTRID.` for `ASTRID^p`

[image]

2. `ASTRID^p` for the paragraph style, living empty the *Change to* field

[image]

Comment: This is definitely one way to go, but would end up changing too much. The issue is that sometimes these characters names appear in the dialogue (ex. NAME. Did you hear what Astrid said?) so I was using the period as the distinguishing mark. I also couldn't use ALL CAPS as the marker since the names appear in stage directions in CAPS as well.

Comment: And changing ASTRID^p for the style? I updated the answer

Comment: Ah, Yep! Keeping it case sensitive and in two parts works.